# Mysql create copy of table and all of the data

Tags: mysql, copy, backup

I need to create a backup copy of  a table and all of the data in it.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT *
INTO copy_cust
FROM Customers;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
CREATE TABLE copy_cust
          AS SELECT *
               FROM Customers
```

Comment: how would i copy  only certain record from a table ?

Comment: use a where clause. like `CREATE TABLE copy_cust AS SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE id = 1`